# Tracking a UITableViewCell pointer with the presence of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier doubts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

suppose I am using the following boiler-plate code  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
    if (cell == nil) {  
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];  
    }  

    // Set up the cell...  
    cell.textLabel.text = [some_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Track the cell
    self.track_Cell = cell ; //<------<<----<<----Suppose I do something like this
    return cell;  
}
```

Now suppose my class has the following property

```
@property(strong , nonatomic) UITableViewCell* track_Cell;
```

Now I read that if my array that will be displayed in the `UITableview`has a total of 10 items and the UITableview visible display is capable of only showing 5 rows then in that case only the no of required visible `UITableViewCell` +2 will be created. So in this case only seven will be created. (I read that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947186/how-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-treat-different-indexpath)) . I also understand that the benefit of using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier` is to recycle already created `UITableViewCell`. If a UITableViewCell is not in view then it is recycled. For instance if row 10 is not in view then the same `UITableviewCell*` that was used for displaying the 10th row might be used to display the 3rd row (Please correct me if I am wrong). Having said that my question is :

**Is it dangerous to use the following statement (that I have used in my code). Especially considering the fact that my table does filtering by attaching to a different NSMutableArray**

```
 track_Cell = cell ;
```

The reason why I am under the impression its dangerous is because suppose I have a `UITableviewCell*` that display data from an array indexed at 2. And now since `UITableviewCells*` are recycled there might be a chance that this same `UITableviewCell` might be pointing to an index of 9 in that array instead of index of 2. Thus saving a pointer to a UITableviewCell with the assumption that it will always be pointing to the second row is wrong. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try to hold on to `indexPath`s rather than the cells themselves. At anytime, you can get the cell representing that indexPath by calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

And your understanding of table view cell recycling is correct, the same cell might be representing indexPath 0-0 at time t=0, but it's possible that at time t=5, it might represent indexPath 0-5.

Comment: so my undrstanding is correct then that holding onto the UITableViewCells pointer is wrong ?